# JSON Schema Documentation Generators

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have looked all over google for hours trying to find a good JSON Schema documentation generator, but I can't seem to find any good ones. Every one listed on http://json-schema.org/implementations has some problem. For Matic, I don't like the look (Actually having brackets, and showing $schema), for Doca, it doesn't work on windows, and for Docson, it can't handle infinite loops. Basically, I want a JSON Schema documentation generator that can

1. Handle infinite reference loops in a good way
2. Can work on windows
3. Has an output that doesn't show the output like Matic, but more like Docson.
4. Has a static output, so the user doesn't have to click anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a hit that works very well. https://github.com/bootprint/bootprint-json-schema is a node module that has the perfect system.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support `patternProperties` at the moment.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to support multiple input files (e.g. if you `$ref` other schemas)...

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/adobe/jsonschema2md - As it's name suggests, generated Markdown from JSON Schema files.

Answer (score 1):

There is also PRMD, although I think it has similar limitations:
https://github.com/interagent/prmd

Hopefully with JSON Hyper-Schema draft-07 about to be published, there will be a new generation of API documentation systems to follow.